# git extensions issue with revert a merge from a branch

Tags: git

i am getting a msg saying 
x--hash of one commit
y-- hash of another commit

You are currently reverting commit x
This reverts commit x, reversing changes made to y.

i want the info on is my branch is going branch with y commit or beyond y?
thanks in Advance

Comment: I do not really understand, can you maybe reword and try to explain with executed commands followed by their errors?

Comment: When reverting a merge commit, git is asking you the changes of which branch you want to revert (so to which commit of the branch merged or the last commit of the branch into which you merge you want to revert). You have to make a choice.